# QTcpServer never reach incomingConnection

Tags: qt, qtcpserver

I try to implement my own server class inheriting `QTcpServer`.

here is the simple code i try to run :

server.cpp

```
MyServer::MyServer(QObject *parent) :
    QTcpServer(parent)
{
}

void MyServer::incomingConnection(qintptr handle)
{
    qDebug() << "Incomming";
    SecureSocket * socket = new SecureSocket(this);
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(StatusMessage(QString)), SIGNAL(StatusMessage(QString)));
    socket->Process(handle);

}
```

main.cpp

```
MyServer serv;
if(serv.listen(QHostAddress::Any,1080))
        console.WriteLine("Listenning on port 1080..."); //Console it's just a class to display message (here it's a simple qDebug())
    else {
       console.WriteLine("Unable to start server");
    }

QThread serverThread;
QObject::connect(&serverThread,SIGNAL(finished()),&serverThread,SLOT(deleteLater()));
serv.moveToThread(&serverThread);
```

My problem is that I never reach the `incommingConnection` (I try a `https://localhost:1080` in my browser as test client) and I actually don't understand why. The server seems to listen properly because as long as the application run, my browser try to load the page, and set a loading error when I quit the application.

P.S. : It's a console application

Comment: What happened when you stepped through this with a debugger?

Comment: I have the same problem here. :-/ I assume it has something to do with the event loop not running correctly.

Comment: @Bastien where you able to solve it?

Comment: Same issue.  No answer available.